# Pass Unity Container to a WPF Converter class

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, unity-container

I am new to WPF.

I would like to know how to dependency inject my IUnityContainer class to a ViewModel that has code only in the XAML.

**Little Update:**
There is a class named: LiveVideoTileControl - I have added the container to it.

I have windows that has a certain Converter:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Driver.Test.Views.LiveVideoTileControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Driver.Test.ViewModel"
         xmlns:Driver="clr-namespace:Driver.Test.DriverRelated"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Driver:CameraToMediaElementConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding  CameraEntity,Converter={StaticResource converter}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

How can i inject a container to class "CameraToMediaElementConverter" ?

```
class CameraToMediaElementConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object cameraEntity, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((cameraEntity as ICameraEntity) != null)
        {
            return DriverWrapper.GetControlForCamera((ICameraEntity)cameraEntity);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to do it manually (FactoryPattern or whatever you like) - this article: http://slickthought.net/post/2011/01/17/Simple-Dependency-Injection-with-XAML.aspx shows how you can inject into properties using pure XAML (but still manually)

Comment: I guess i can wrap my 2 parameters in 1 and send it as the object to the Convert(object wrapperObj) .. instead of sending 1 object in the Convert(..)

Comment: no - that will make your code unreadable - have you had a look at the article I linked? Settings a property for the `converter` right there in your XAML seems to be a good option IMO

Comment: The article is talking about injecting it to the ViewModel, not to a static converter class that i used inside the view model..

Comment: where is the difference in this case? One you declare as DataContext the other as Resource

Comment: What Type is CameraEntity ? 
Is it the same instance , or can it change ? 
At what point would you like the CameraEntity to Change instances ( i.e. Resolve either another instance or the same one ) ?

Comment: I Use the container and camera entity in order to get camera driver. the container has a certain provider registered in it, the provider receive the entity and give me a driver..

Answer (score 4):

If someone will get here somehow and will still look for an answer, this is what I did in my application and it works just fine. The limitation of a converter class is that you cannot pass a reference to an instance of a unity container to inject your service via the constructor.

In the Bootstrapper class or any other place you register your services on startup (Here it's part of the Prism's bootstrapper ConfigureContainer):

```
   protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType<IShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>();
        Container.RegisterType<MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterInstance<MyService>(new MyService());
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("IoC", this.Container);
    }
```

Pay attention to the last line:

```
            Application.Current.Resources.Add("IoC", this.Container);
```

and in the converter class ctor:

```
        UnityContainer unityContainer = (UnityContainer)Application.Current.Resources["IoC"];
```

Now you can easily resolve any instance of an object from the Unity container:

```
service = (MyService) unityContainer.Resolve<MyService>();
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution, however I had to change a little your code when resolving UnityContainer in this way: 
`UnityContainerExtension unityContainer = (UnityContainerExtension)Application.Current.Resources["IoC"];`
Also when resolving the service: `var service = (IMyService) unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(IMyService));`